# create a pie chart from api response

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart, pie-chart

I want to create a pie chart using the API response, but it doesn't work
here's how I get the data:

```
 Future getPie() async{
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse("url"));
  final js = jsonDecode(response.body);
  return js;
}
```

then I create the pie in a future builder

```
 FutureBuilder(
            future: getPie(),
            builder: (ctx,AsyncSnapshot ss){
              if(ss.hasData){
                return SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Container(
                    child: Center(
                      child: PieChart(
                        dataMap: ss.data,
                        chartRadius: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.7,
                        legendOptions: LegendOptions(
                          legendPosition: LegendPosition.bottom
                        ),
                        
                      )
                    ),
                  )
                );
              }else{
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              }
            }
        ),
```

this is the API response

```
 { 
   'a' : 2
   'b' : 5
 }
```

but I get an error :

> type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, double>'

I also tried using a map but manually work and from API doesn't :

```
Future getPie() async{


final response = await http.get(Uri.parse("url"));
final js = jsonDecode(response.body);
final  a= js['a'];
final  b= js['b'];

//this work
final Map<String, double> data = {};
data['a'] = 4;
data['b'] = 5;

//this doesn't
final Map<String, double> data = {};
data['a'] = a;
data['b'] = b;

print(data);

return data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead:

```
Future getPie() async {
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse("url"));
  final js = jsonDecode(response.body);
  var res = Map.fromEntries(js.entries.map((e) => MapEntry<String, double>(e.key, e.value.toDouble())));
  return res;
}
```

Comment: var res is not working and its blocking the method, because when i print anything after it, nothing appears and the method never end but when print anything before (res) i got what i printed. So res is the problem here